# Getting Dutch Schengen visa from the Italian embassy

Tags: schengen, netherlands

Our relatives are residents of the US. We invited them to visit us in this summer.

Unfortunately they live quite far from Dutch embassies but fortunately there is an Italian embassy in their state. I know two countries are not related but would it be possible to get visas in Italian embassy. Just to save time and money for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is sometimes possible but only if the two countries have an agreement to do it and, as far as I know, that's not the case for the Netherlands and Italy in the US.

Such agreements are getting more common but very often it's between neighbouring countries (e.g. the Benelux, Nordic countries) and in places where the destination country does not have any representation. You cannot generally apply to any consulate from any Schengen country.

In this particular case, the Netherlands does have an embassy in Washington and [it seems it's not possible to apply elsewhere](http://www.government.nl/issues/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/documents-and-publications/publications/2014/02/20/embassies-responsible-for-short-stay-visa-for-the-netherlands.html). You could still inquire at the embassy to see if some other arrangement is possible but it does not look like it.